# JQuery doesn't work in IE locally, but works fine on the server

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Right, rewrite my question:

Here is a very simple bit of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>IE Test</title>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">click</a>
</body>
```

When I upload to the server here at www.green-itea.com/test_place, everything works fine: when you click the 'click' link, it hides as the jquery suggests.

However,

When I run the exactly same file locally in my computer in IE to test, there is no errors, but when I click the 'click' link, it doesn't hide, which means the jQuery didn't work at all.

Another thing: locally, other browsers all work fine except IE. I have enabled the script in Internet setting options as well.

I have no idea why this will happen, Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you write the versions of IE you are using. Perhaps versions are different in your pc and the server.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Consider posting any of your code else we will have to guess our asses off

Comment: I tried 7, 8 and 9 used the developer tool in IE, all the same

Comment: i seen your site and found that you have jQuery in root directory so make sure jQuery is loaded in local and jQuery js is present in folder..

Comment: here is an example: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>IE Test</title>
 <!-- jquery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">click</a>
</body>

Comment: Is it giving the $ not defined error or what? What do you mean by jQuery doesn't work?

Comment: which part is not working?

Comment: On the server, it worked. As I said, it WORKED on the server. But it DOESN'T WORK locally in my machine, the click doesn't hide as it does on the server.

Comment: @the_summer_bee Edit your question and add the HTML!

Comment: @the_summer_bee Check the IE console (hit F12) for errors when viewing your local copy.

Comment: on server it worked means? did you host the app in server and browsed in your IE? or browsed in server IE itself. i'll recommend to try it with other systems too for confirming it is browser setting issue.

Comment: Did you host your application in IIS? or running it from file location or IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you turned off Javascript on your browser? Sometimes it is an annoying security feature for IE that you may have turned on without knowing.

From : http://www.activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/ie

PC
In the Tools drop-down menu, select Internet Options.
Next, select the Security tab.
Then, select the earth (Internet) icon.
Then select the Custom Level button.
Locate Scripting near the bottom of the list.
Under Active Scripting, select Enable, then hit OK.
Answer yes to the following conformation box.
Hit OK to close the Internet Options window.
Finally, hit refresh on your browser window to enjoy the javascript.

Comment: Turning off javascript while using jQuery. Good job that won't work

Comment: @s.lenders They're saying to check that JavaScript isn't turned off, not saying to turn it off. However, I'd assume the question asker is using the same browser to check both the local and server version of the page, so it's probably not going to be that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Well initialy he phrased it like he should disable it, but he edited it.

Comment: Right, I am so not familiar with IE. Totally ignored the yellow window showed up in the bottom when I opened IE locally, which says:the script is restricted, do you want to turn it on...I kept closing it without reading it. silly me. thank you for reminding. well spot! :) By the way, even so, I hate IE, never felt guilty to say that :( happy coding...